# Android Volley synchronous request not working

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to make a **synchronous request** to the server using **RequestFuture** but it's not working . The same request when done using asynchronous works fine.

This is my code:

```
 public void fetchModules(){
   JSONObject response = null;
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Url.ALL_MODULES_URL,null,future,future);
    requestQueue.add(request);


    try {
         response = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Blocks for at most 10 seconds.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             Log.d(TAG,"interupted");
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"execution");
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d(TAG,response.toString());
}
```

I am getting a nullpointerexception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
>                                                                      at com.maths.app.AllModules.fetchModules(AllModules.java:85)
>                                                                      at com.maths.app.AllModules.onCreateView(AllModules.java:51)
>                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
>                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
>                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
>                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
>                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
>                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

it's returning a null response. How can I solve this?

Comment: If response !=null then log.d (blabla);

Comment: ?????? Please go through the question again!!!

Comment: what about increasing the timeout little more and test again!!

Comment: May be because of the main Thread. Try to use a different thread other than main thread. just for knowing the reason . Normally android will throw an exception if we do some network operation in main thread check the logs .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

tl;dr; 
**You got deceived by the try-catch**

Explanation:
Because the `RequestFuture.get()`is probably running on the UI thread you are really getting a `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` behind the scenes. **That is the default behaviour when the calls gets executed on the main thread.**

The try catch stops the app from crashing, nevertheless the **response is still a null reference** which crashes the app when you try to `Log`the result.
If you comment the following line you will see that the app doesn't crash (there) anymore.

> Log.d(TAG,response.toString());

Fix: Making the RequestFuture network call **on another thread**!

One way to do it:

```
    public class TestVolley {

    private String TAG = "SO_TEST";
    private String url = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/1/";


    public JSONObject fetchModules(Context ctx){
        JSONObject response = null;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);


        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url,null,future,future);
        requestQueue.add(request);


        try {
            response = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Blocks for at most 10 seconds.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"interrupted");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"execution");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG,response.toString());

        return response;
    }
}
```

The `AsyncTask` which will make the network call :

```
public class MyVolleyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String, JSONObject> {

    private Context ctx;

    public MyVolleyAsyncTask(Context hostContext)
    {
        ctx = hostContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Method runs on a separate thread, make all the network calls you need
        TestVolley tester = new TestVolley();

        return tester.fetchModules(ctx);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
       // runs on the UI thread
       // do something with the result
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this is your old code which will crash the app
        //TestVolley tester = new TestVolley();
        //tester.fetchModules(this);

        // Works!
        new MyVolleyAsyncTask(this).execute();
    }
}
```

result:

```
com.so.henriquems.testvolleyfuture D/SO_TEST: {"id":1,"pokemon":{"url":"http:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/pokemon\/1\/","name":"bulbasaur"},[...]
```

Hope this helps

cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answering but There are objects that needs to be initialized in the main thread using the response. I have tried using asynchronous task  the response works fine but the objects  are null.

Comment: @Jois that is why you have the Listeners - objects which will react when the response arrives, no need to make the UI thread wait  ;)

Comment: I have no other option other than do the job in a background thread. is there a way to update the ui in volley??

Comment: I think I found a way.

Comment: @Jois I thought it was a strange train of thought you were following, please give some more details about what you want to achieve and I will help you tomorrow. For now i can tell you that although the network call can't run on the Ui thread, it is a common pattern to pass it's result to the ui  thread (see onPostExecute above)  you have many ways to get your response to the ui that is one way

Comment: it's fine I found a solution!

Comment: @Jois alright then ;)     if you can please mark the question as answered =) if you still need clarification come back and I'll help you tomorrow. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

We can use RxJava.

Lets assume that the **fetchModules** method  returns JSONObject

```
Observable<JSONObject> moduleObservable = Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends JSONObject>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<? extends JSONObject> call() throws Exception {
            return Observable.just(fetchModules());
        }
    });
```

In MainActivity

```
moduleObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new io.reactivex.Observer<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(JSONObject response) {
                    // Your response is here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                     showAlert(context, e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching this question myself, you CAN'T (at the moment of writing) do it in the main thread

I want Volley to do it in the main thread because I need to block until Volley finish getting response. And this is not possible, synchronous request on Volley must be in an async thread, not in the main thread.

The work around that I have done is, doing the subsequent codes inside the onResponse method of Volley request