# How to get POJO from a volley callback, and use/return it in the calling function?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm implementing a simple mobile app with user accounts. Additionally, it must be structured in a layered architecture that cleanly separates presentation, logic and access to the database.
I'm currently able to send and get data from a server, using the volley library. However, this data is only available inside the `onResponse` method of the `Response.Listener<String>` passed as a parameter in the constructor of `stringRequest` object, later used to perform the request. I want to use the data that I get in the response to construct a User object that I could use all over my app, and keep the layered architecture as much as possible.

This is an example of the kind of method I've been aiming for:

```
public ResponseType insertUser (final Context context, final String id, final String name, final String password) {

    //using a wrapper object because have to declare object as final to use
        //inside inner class, so use field to assign value
    final ResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, BuildConfig.ip,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    wrapper.response = response.equals("") ?
                                        ResponseWrapper.SUCCESS :
                                        ResponseWrapper.DB_ERROR;
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    wrapper.response = ResponseWrapper.CONNECTION_ERROR;
                }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("id",id);
                params.put("name",name);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    //waiting for callback to modify field
    while(wrapper.response == null);

    return wrapper.response;
}
```

I've tried setting a field of an external object inside `onResponse`, waiting for the field to be changed to continue execution, to no avail. The code compiles and performs the request, but the field is kept unchanged. My research has suggested to me that this is something to be expected when dealing with asynchronous code.

Most examples I've read limit their scope to using `Toast` to show the response in the screen. A couple change activities inside the method, but this goes against the layer separation that I'm trying to achieve by performing presentation actions inside the database access layer (and potentially performing business logic too, as my app becomes more complex).

So, how can I get an object from inside the callback? (For example the `String` containing the response, or an enum indicating the result of an operation).
If this isn't possible or advisable, how could I structure the code to keep the separation of concerns?

My thanks in advance for any suggestion that could steer me in the right direction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122481/1197251

Comment: Many thanks @dominicoder. That answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729831/8076041) about why not use `RequestFuture` in the UI thread were what I needed. For reference to people having a similar problem, the combination of `RequestFuture` and `AsyncTask` was what worked for me.